# How to use preventBack() to refresh a page when pressing back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code forwards if pressing back button in both iOS & Android:

```
    <script type = "text/javascript" >
    function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload=function(){null};
    </script>
```

This code refreshes a page when hitting or swiping back in iOS but not working in android:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    onload=function(){
    var e=document.getElementById("refreshed");
    if(e.value=="no")e.value="yes";
    else{e.value="no";location.reload();}
    }
    </script>
```

So can we make a code that works in both iOS & android to refresh when hitting back or swiping back using preventBack() function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, this will helps you to stop click back and reload the page too.

```
function preventBack() {
  history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
  window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    location.reload();
  });
}
```